# Finding last digits in text using stringr

Tags: r, stringr

Trying to use StringR to find all the digits which occur at the end of the text.

For example

```
x <- c("Africa-123-Ghana-2", "Oceania-123-Sydney-200")
```

and StringR operation should return

```
"2  200"
```

I believe there might be multiple methods, but what would be the best code for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: yes, i tried using str_match, but i guess couldn't figure out the reverse (right to left) lookup.

Comment: You are supposed to share what you have tried.

Comment: str_match(x,"^(\\d+)")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
sub(".*-(\\d+)$", "\\1", x)
#[1] "2"   "200"
```

Or

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+$")
```

Or

```
stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d+")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regexpr/regmatches` in `base R` to match one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+$", x))
#[1] "2"   "200"
```

---

Or with `sub`, we match characters until the last character that is not a digit and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub(".*\\D+", "", x)
#[1] "2"   "200"
```

---

Or using `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "-"), tail, 1)
#[1] "2"   "200"
```

---

Or using `stringr` with `str_match`

```
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "(\\d+)$")[,1]
#[1] "2"   "200"
```

Or with `str_remove`

```
str_remove(x, ".*\\D+")
#[1] "2"   "200"
```